# docker-compose build with multiple services in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker-compose, I have built a simple web application using flask and redis and it works fine in my localhost, my question is how to push this web app including the python and redis images to docker hub and pull that image from a different machine.

I usually do docker-compose build, 
docker push

```
version: '3'
services:
 web:
  build: .
  image: "alhaffar/flask_redis_app:2.0"
  ports:
   - "8088:5000"
  depends_on:
   - redis
 redis:
  image: "redis:alpine"
```

the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

# CHANGE WORKIN DIR AND COPY FILES
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

# INSTALL REQUIRED PACAKGES
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# RUN THE APP
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

when I try to pull the image into a different machine and issue docker run, it runs only the python image without redis image.

how I can run all images

Comment: You need your private repo, need to login into that repo, push your image, then login again on other machine and pull the image. That can be done with public hub, but if you're not going to share you app with community, private repo is probably the best option. BTW, GitLab has built-in private repo (though it might be a bit cumbersome to setup).

Comment: Also, just to make it clear: docker-compose works with a stack of images/services, while docker registry works with images one by one -- it does not store any dependencies defined in your docker-compose.yml. This does not change much in your question or my answer, just thought it'd be better if I clarify that.

Comment: Another "also", you're saying stock image "redis" is not pulled? Not your custom image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerhub and other docker registries work with images. Docker-compose is just an abstraction which helps to set up a bunch of images, that can work together, by using one configuration-file - docker-compose. There is nothing like docker-compose registries. Then if you have your docker-compose file on the other machine you just use `docker-compose up` and images should be pulled - assuming they are published to some registry (public/private). Image with your app should be published by you and refis will be taken form dockerhub registry, if you are using redis official image.

Docker-compose is helpful when you are doing some local development and want to set up your working environment quickly. If you want to set up this environment on other machine you would have to share the docker-compose file with them and have the docker and docker-compose installed on that other machine.

If your docker-compose is configured to build some image on start, you can still push this image using [`docker-compose push`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/) command.

Answer (score 1):

With your Docker Compose Script you do two things:

1. Build your Flask App —> Image 1
2. Pull and run Redis —> Image 2

If you push Image 1 to DockerHub and pull it on an other machine, you are missing the second Image.

What you want to do is run the Docker compose script on the second machine without the `build` line.